# Math "non loop" equation

Tags: java, math, equation

I am creating a **Java** program but am dealing with a math problem but can't seem to solve it. This is my assignment:

```
I have infinite numbers of numbered papers(1,2,3, ..). 
This papers are stacked into stacks using 2 variables a and b.

If a = 5 and b = 3 the stacks look like:
```

[image]

```
So the first stack has "a" items (5) and each next has "b" more (3) as previous.
```

Now I have to figure out *an equation* that would tell me *how many papers I need to remove to get to the specific one*.

**For example**, if I want to get to the paper numbered with 20, I will need to remove 4 papers to get to it. And this is the solution I am looking for, when I would enter a number of a specific paper, I just need to know how many I need to move (in the stack that it is in) to get to it. When I have this *I put all papers back* and search for the next one.

Since I will make a program with it, that will deal with long numbers (up to 16 digits), the best solution would be to find some "non loop" equation. For example, if I will set a = 34354 and b = 56774 and I want to know how many papers to remove to get to paper numbered with 533663634611112.

My **inputs** will be: 
 - numbers a and b 
 - number of papers I want to reach (c) 
 - regarding the above variable (c), I will input this many numbers that represent numbered papers

**Output**: 
   - number of papers I have to move to get to all the papers that I have inserted

All number will be very long, so would be the best to make a non loop program.
Thanks for all help about this issue.

Comment: Is it related to programming? Why is there lots of *s-h-i-t-s*?

Comment: Add the programming language tag and include your code to the question. Right now the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Actuanlly I am just looking for that part of code that will return the number of papers that need moving for reaching specific paper. I want to make all other stuff on my own, arent looking for the entire program.

Comment: So **a** is the initial stack size, and **b** is the incrementation of the stack's size. Are you sure you can solve this without a loop? Unless you somehow write the recursive formula to determine the index, then use the formula for linear recursion to make it be a closed formula. I was trying to figure out a recursive formula just now, but I kinda got stuck and I'm at work so my time is limited, sorry.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying, actually I need the top paper number of that stack in which the indexed paper is in.
Since number of papers that I will be searching for can be up to 5 digit number and that the paper numbers can be up to 16 digits, think that the loop would take to long. Having it for all searched papers yes, but not having a nested one for searching hoe many papers to move for each.

Comment: Getting the answer you're looking for seems better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops for this. The number of papers in the `n`th pile is `a + (n-1)b`. So the number of papers in the first `n` piles is (arithmetic series) `(b/2)n^2 + (a - b/2)n`.

Using this, find the number of piles needed to get your paper. In your example, set this equal to 20 (and use 3 and 5). So you have `20 = 1.5n^2 + 3.5n`. [Solving this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E2%20%2B7x%20-40%20%3D%200) (using the quadratic formula) gives `n = -5` and `n = 8/3`. Ignore the negative one as it doesn't make sense in this situation.

If you need 8/3 piles to get to your paper, it must be in the 3rd pile (round up to nearest int (ceiling function)). Use the formula above with `n = 3` to find there are 24 papers in the first three piles (`1.5 * 3^2 + 3.5 * 3 = 13.5 + 10.5 = 24`).

24 - 20 = 4 = the number of papers you need to remove.

[mockup solution, you need to remove hardcoding and make sure nothing overflows for the large numbers](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0f4156d958a9f62f99c)

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of loop to do this. I can help with the math, but someone else may have to help with the programming

```
j=1
TOTAL = ja + (j-1)b
If the TOTAL is less than c, then let j=j+1 and loop
If the TOTAL is greater than c, end the loop (this loop shouldn't take too long)
Then calc TOTAL - c from it to get your answer
```

That method should work. But a presume a loop like this shouldnt take much power even with long numbers.

Comment: Thanks but not quite sure what you meant. Yes, for searching c papers i Will have a loop that will go from 1 to c. But then inside this loop, how to manage the inserted papers number and get the answer how many to move. Can you explain the formula on the example I ahve given a= 5 and b is 3, we are looking for paper numbered 20.

Answer (score 0):

Mathy answer, but it might be enough to help you:

Stack number is the single integer solution of two inequalities:

```
ax + b(x-1)> argument AND a(x-1) + b(x-2) < argument
```

Whether that can be computed without using a loop I cannot say and I don't know of any library that could help you (though I am not an expert in math Java libraries). After that the answer you're looking for is

```
a*x + b(x-1) - argument
```